# Is it possible to delete an entire Webpage when the user navigates away?

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, cookies

If the user navigates off the webpage, is it possible to execute a php script?

I know that Javascript can be executed..

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'DataTest';
});
```

Cookies might work, but I am not sure how a listener could track an expired cookie, and then delete the correct webpage.

A sample file system is like this:

- user0814HIFA9032RHBFAP3RU.php
- user9IB83BFI19Y298RYBFWOF.php
- index.php
- listener.py
- data.txt

Typically, to create the website, php writes to the data.txt and the Python listener picks up this change, and creates the file (user[numbers]). As you might think, these files stack up overtime and they need to be deleted.

Comment: Did you think of sending an Ajax request?

Comment: @Jivan No, I didn't think of that. How could you use AJAX in conjunction with deleting a page?

Comment: If these are just expired temporary files, use a daily cron job to delete them after they are a day old (or whatever time delay you wish to use).

Comment: @jayumz I tried to answer the question in your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm not sure, as Fox pointed out, that this is the right way to go in your case.** I actuallly upvoted Fox's answer.

However, if you absolutely need to delete each page right after the user left it, use this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    $.ajax('yourscript.php?currentUser=0814HIFA9032RHBFAP3RU');
});
```

Then in yourscript.php, put something like the following:

```
<?php

// load your userId (for example, with $_SESSION, but do what you want here)
$actualUser = $_SESSION['userId'];

// checks if the requested id to delete fits your actual current user's id
if (isset($_GET['currentUser'] && $_GET['currentUser'] == $actualUser)
{
    $user = $_GET['currentUser'];
    $file = 'user'.$user.'.php';

    unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work. The name passed is a variable, but I can easily place it in the ajax call. Thank you :)

Comment: hey, if an attacker would know the userId of another user, he could send/type yourscript.php?currentUser=foobarUser, so this might be an security vuln. So although this is a good answer, check, if the user has the permissions to delete ...

Answer (score 2):

The http protocol is stateless, therefore users simply can not "navigate away".
The browser requires a page, the server returns it, and the communication stops.
The server doesn't have reliable methods to know what the client will do with that page.